# Can't start Ipython: no module named ipython

Tags: python, ipython

I'm trying to install iPython on a Mac and am running into several problems. I believe the build script may be saving ipython to the wrong location but am unsure how to resolve this properly.

Initially I tried installing using pip, which gave the following error:

`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/bg/68k19b6d6hbgwfcgvgy0dtvr0000gn/T/pip-build-qXqxr3/simplegeneric`

So I tried building from the tarball instead. This succeeded without any errors but when I tried to start ipython I got the error

`File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 4, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
ImportError: No module named IPython`

The contents of /usr/local/bin/ipython are as follows:

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
# This script was automatically generated by setup.py
    if __name__ == '__main__':
    from IPython import start_ipython
    start_ipython()
```

I tried updating pip, reinstalling python via homebrew, and consistently run into the same problem. I was able to successfully install numpy, scipy, and matplotlib, all of which appear in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages while ipython does not.

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Are you trying to install IPython or IPython Notebook?

Comment: For now, just IPython

Comment: what command did you use to install from source?

Comment: $ tar -xzf ipython-4.1.1.tar.gz

then 

sudo python setup.py install --prefix=/usr/local